# How do i center the buttons?

Tags: html, css, navigation

I want the buttons (contact, etc) to be in the middle of the navigation bar, tried alot of things, but it just wont suceed.
Any help would be apreciated alot!

[image: Menu bar]

CSS:

```
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu li,
#cssmenu span,
#cssmenu a {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}
#cssmenu {
  height: 49px;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  background: #141414;
  background:url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAAxCAIAAACUDVRzAA3NCSVQICAjb4U/gAAAALElEQVQImWMwMrJi+v//PxMDw3+m//8ZoPR/qBgDEhuXGLoeYswhXg8R5gAAdVpfoJ3dB5oAASUVORK5CYII=) 100% 100%; 
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #32323a 0%, #141414 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #32323a), color-stop(100%, #141414));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #32323a 0%, #141414 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #32323a 0%, #141414 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #32323a 0%, #141414 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #32323a 0%, #141414 100%);
  border-bottom: 2px solid #0fa1e0;
}
#cssmenu:after,
#cssmenu ul:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
#cssmenu a {
  background: #141414;
  background:url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAAxCAIAAACUDVRzAA3NCSVQICAjb4U/gAAAALElEQVQImWMwMrJi+v//PxMDw3+m//8ZoPR/qBgDEhuXGLoeYswhXg8R5gAAdVpfoJ3dB5oAASUVORK5CYII=) 100% 100%; 
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #32323a 0%, #141414 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #32323a), color-stop(100%, #141414));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #32323a 0%, #141414 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #32323a 0%, #141414 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #32323a 0%, #141414 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #32323a 0%, #141414 100%);
  color: #ff;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 49px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#cssmenu ul {
  list-style: none;
}
#cssmenu > ul {
  float: left;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li {
  float: left;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid #0fa1e0;
  margin-left: -10px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:first-child > a {
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:last-child > a {
  border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.active > a {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px black;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px black;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px black;
  background: #070707;
  background:url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAAxCAIAAACUDVRzAA3NCSVQICAjb4U/gAAAALklEQVQImWNQU9Nh+v//PxMDw3+m//8ZkNj/mRgYIHxy5f//Z0BSi18e2TwS5QG4MGB54HL+mAABJRU5ErkJggg==) 100% 100%; 
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #26262c 0%, #070707 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #26262c), color-stop(100%, #070707));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #26262c 0%, #070707 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #26262c 0%, #070707 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #26262c 0%, #070707 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #26262c 0%, #070707 100%);
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a {
  background: #070707;
  background:url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAAxCAIAAACUDVRzAA3NCSVQICAjb4U/gAAAALklEQVQImWNQU9Nh+v//PxMDw3+m//8ZkNj/mRgYIHxy5f//Z0BSi18e2TwS5QG4MGB54HL+mAABJRU5ErkJggg==) 100% 100%; 
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #26262c 0%, #070707 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #26262c), color-stop(100%, #070707));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #26262c 0%, #070707 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #26262c 0%, #070707 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #26262c 0%, #070707 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #26262c 0%, #070707 100%);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px black;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px black;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px black;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub {
  z-index: 1;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub ul li {
  *margin-bottom: -1px;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub ul li a {
  background: #0fa1e0;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #6fc7ec;
  filter: none;
  font-size: 11px;
  display: block;
  line-height: 120%;
  padding: 10px;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub ul li:hover a {
  background: #0c7fb0;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub .has-sub:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub .has-sub ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub .has-sub ul li a {
  background: #0c7fb0;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #6db2d0;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub .has-sub ul li a:hover {
  background: #095c80;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>
   <li class='active'><a href='index.html'><span>About</span></a></li>
   <li><a href='#'><span>Bookings</span></a></li>
   <li><a href='#'><span>Contact</span></a></li>
   <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Back to the Portal</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: li should be set inline or inline-block and not floatting, so, text-align:center; on ul can do the job :) , you could as well instead set ul display:table;+margin:auto;

Comment: @GCyrillus you should post as an answer

Comment: Thank you very much!
You really helped me out mate!
Really apreciated!

Comment: Thanks man ^^ apreciate the feedback : )

Answer (score 0):

As advise from koala_dev, here's comments hint turned into  as answer. :)

If you wish to center your links you can either use:

```
ul {
    text-align:center;
}
li {
    display:inline-block; /* or even just inline */
}
```

if you wish to center ul without giving width, you can use :

```
ul {
    display:table;
    margin:auto;
}
li {
   /* use either float or display:inline/inline-block/table-cell/inline-table... any inline-level-box display*/
}
```